# Recorrer el webrequest al web.config

Tags: c#

Necesito mover esto:

`string postData = "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=488E-AEE9-0FED26EAA258&INPUT_DATA=" + sendXML;`

`System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://service.mx:8080/sdpapi/request/");`

al webconfig help...

Answer (score 0):

Podrias definir la entrada como ser

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="postData" value="OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=488E-AEE9-0FED26EAA258&INPUT_DATA=" />
      <add key="url" value="http://service.mx:8080/sdpapi/request/" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

enonces si agregar la referencia a `System.Configuration` usarias

```
  string postData= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["postData"];
```

asi tomarias los datos de la configuracion